# Can't upload picture from client to server using jsp/servlets

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I'm trying to upload a picture from a client to the server with jsp/java servlets, but I'm having some difficulties...

It seems like the process is completed but I can't find the copied file anywhere...

Here's what I have so far:

index.jsp

```
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form action="FileUploadServlet" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" size="50" accept="image/*" name="browseButton">
            <input style="width: 7em" type=submit value="Upload" name="uploadButton">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

FileUploadServlet.java (only relevant part)

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    ServletFileUpload upload=new ServletFileUpload(new DiskFileItemFactory());
    try {

        FileItemStream item=upload.getItemIterator(request).next();

        String pictureOnServer=getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
        // pictureOnServer: /home/****/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/TestProject/
        File fileOnServer=new File(pictureOnServer+File.separator+"pics"+File.separator+"fileNameOnServer");

        FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(fileOnServer);
        InputStream is=item.openStream();

        byte[] buffer=new byte[8*1024];
        int length;
        while ((length=is.read())>0) {
            fos.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        fos.flush();
        fos.close();

    } catch (FileUploadException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
}
```

When I run index.jsp, I get:
[image]

I then click "Browse..." and choose some picture named "picture.jpg", and click "Upload", but the file will not get copied:
[image]

There's nothing in the "pics" folder as you can see... (even after refreshing)

Does anyone know what went wrong?

Comment: What's the value of pictureOnServer? What's the value of fileOnServer? Why do you think it's a good idea to upload files to a directory that is part of the sources of the application? Do you realize that your actual server, where you'll deploy the war file, won't have any directory named "WebContent"?

Comment: I've edited the post, and added pictureOnServer's value.  
Where should I upload the picutres to?

Comment: So now you have your answer. The file you're looking for is under /home/****/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/TestProject/, which is where Eclipse deploys your application. You should upload your pictures to a directory that is not in your development environment (because it only exists on a development machine), and not, as you're doing, in the directory where the application is deployed (because this directory might not even exist, and because the next deployment will delete everything from this directory).

Comment: Use a configurable property (using the web.xml file, or a properties file, or whatever) to configure an absolute base path for your uploads.